# Cannot access to selector of div that is created by jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to access selector that I created it by using html() of jquery function. I tried many solutions from few websites, but it doesn't work. Now, I make an example, please correct it and tell me the reason

Please see example here

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".close").click(function(){
     alert("message closed");
   });
   $("button").click(function(){
    $("#msg").html('<div class="close">Close</div><div>Message...</div>');
   });
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the `close` is created dynamically, you need to use event delegation

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#msg').on('click', ".close", function () {
        alert("message closed");
    });
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("#msg").html('<div class="close">Close</div><div>Message...</div>');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kmGZD/)

Comment: What is difference between click() and on()?

Comment: @lyhong it is not the difference between `on` and `click` - `click` internally used `on` to register the handler. The difference is event delegation